# Why binding this list is not working on POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LaunchVisualiser(IList<VisualiserModel> selectedVisualisers, int implicitSelectedVisualiserId)
    {
        List<int> selectedSearchQueries = searchQueryRepository.GetSearchQueriesOfStreamsIds(selectedVisualisers.Where(v => v.Selected == true).Select(v => v.Stream.Id).ToList());
   // rest of my code
    }
```

and in the view:

```
@model List<SocialCrm.Models.VisualiserModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LaunchVisualiser", "Platform", new { implicitSelectedVisualiserId = ViewBag.CurrentVisualiser.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
    {
        if (Model[i].Id == ViewBag.CurrentVisualiser.Id)
        {
            continue;
        }

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Stream.Id)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Selected)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Name)
    </div>
    }
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="temp" value="Launch Visualiser" />
}
```

I simply don't understand why `selectedVisualisers` is always null when doing POST.

Do you have any clue? I saw many examples like this, maybe I am missing something...

**UPDATE**:

Generated html is:

```
<form action="/platform/launchvisualiser?implicitSelectedVisualiserId=1" method="post">
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[1].Stream.Id" type="hidden" value="9">    <div class="editor-label">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="[1].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[1].Selected" type="hidden" value="false">
        test java hiring visualiser
    </div>
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[2].Stream.Id" type="hidden" value="8">    <div class="editor-label">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." name="[2].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[2].Selected" type="hidden" value="false">
        vis test
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="temp" value="Launch Visualiser">
</form>
```

and this is sent to the server in Form Data (inspected with Chrome):

```
[1].Stream.Id:9
[1].Selected:true
[1].Selected:false
[2].Stream.Id:8
[2].Selected:false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Stream.Id)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Selected)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
</div>
```

By the way when you inspected the generated HTML of this Razor view I hope the `if` statement wasn't hit multiple times and inside your `<form>` element you had at least some inputs.

Use FireBug or Chrome developer toolbar in order to inspect what exactly gets sent to the server as payload of the POST request.

Also there's a problem with this `continue;` statement. This can potentially leave *holes* in the indexes that you are submitting to the server which is invalid according to the expected format of the default [`model binder for binding to a list`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

When you inspect the POST payload in Fiddler you should not see that (it is problematic):

```
[0].Stream.Id = 5
[0].Selected = true
[0].Name = name 1
[2].Stream.Id = 7
[2].Selected = true
[2].Name = name 4
```

Notice the *hole* in the indexes which could occur if the `continue` statement gets hit. In order to fix that I would recommend you using *non-sequential indexes*. Read Phil Haack's article I've linked to previously in my answer if you haven't already done so. He explains non-sequential indexes in a separate section. So go ahead, use them. Steven Sanderson illustrated an excellent `Html.BeginCollectionItem` custom helper in his excellent [*Editing Variable Length List in ASP.NET MVC*](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) blog post that you could adapt to your needs.